# Are these two OP-AMP circuits behaving different?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am looking for DC biasing circuit for a bipolar square wave with frequency < 10 MHz.
I'd like to make a square wave with high 1.5-1.7 V and low (-1.5)-(-1.7) V into a square wave with high ~ 5 V and low ~ 0 V, such that midpoint is 2.5 V

And I've found two examples.

[The First one](http://www.daycounter.com/Circuits/OpAmp-Level-Shifter/OpAmp-Level-Shifter.phtml) is like:

[image]

And [the second one](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Amplifiers/amplifiers66.php) is like:

[image]

As I have little knowledge about circuit, I am wondering if they are behaving same or not.

A signal in the first circuit is fed into (+), but in the second circuit, it is fed into (-). I think both circuit will output inverted waveform respect to each other. Is it right, or do I have a wrong understanding of circuits?

Comment: I found some article explaining OP-AMP written in Korean. It says, if there is negative feedback on OP-AMP, Vin+ and Vin- becomes same. And the output voltage can be calculated from that hint. I will try calculation.

Comment: If someone can read Korean, http://www.senslab.co.kr/Class/OPAMP%C6%AF%B0%AD.pdf

Comment: why not just a comparator

Comment: You could use a RUM002N02 MOSFET and a resistor if the output voltage is to be fixed at the supply rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are behaving differently.

- The first one is not inverting. The second one is inverting.

  To be more accurate the output signal in the second one should look like  this (phase inverted; also the amplitude may be changed, depending on R1 || R2 and R4):
  [image]

  For most audio purposes or many other cases it doesn't matter if phase is inverted along the signal path or not.
- And of course the first circuit includes a (quite) low pass filter consisting of R? (100kOhm) and  C? (100nF) at the output.

  The second circuit doesn't. That's a big difference.